# Client stuck after login

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a problem with my client computers. There are times that when I login to any client computers, I get stuck on the welcome screen and it keeps loading. My client computers use Windows 8.1.

Comment: Does Windows log anything in the event logs to give you any hint as to what the problem could be?

Comment: There's no log recorded. Actually for clarification, It's not stuck at all its just took a lot of minutes to logon. I think its because of my folder redirection all my files are in the server.

Comment: Have a look at this http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/06/09/slow-boot-slow-logon-sbsl-a-tool-called-xperf-and-links-you-need-to-read.aspx I had to use it recently to find out what was going on with long login times...